# Firefox does not display URL while invoked from Python-Selenium

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I have tried to use the sample code mentioned on the http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium which will invoke the Firefox browser and put URL into address bar.

The Firefox browser does get launched but it does not put the URL in address and program throws exception with out sufficient information..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/paithankar/Desktop/test", line 6, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 46, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 102, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 153, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 125, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
WebDriverException: Message: ''
```

Does some one know about what is the wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the java selenium driver? ... 
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar

Comment: I don't think so. Do I have it keep running on my machine?

Comment: Yes, you need to keep it running.

Comment: BTW, I am using Selenium 2, which does not need this jar to be running.

Comment: The link you posted is for Selenium 2, and that is what says to run the jar.

Comment: No luck even after running server...same issue

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Server doesn't need to be running with the Selenium 2 WebDriver.

From SeleniumHQ:  "If you will be only using the WebDriver API you do not need the Selenium-Server."

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#webdriver-and-the-selenium-server